# Что делать, если в Яндексе ссылки с www, когда сайт переехал на без?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Месяца два назад сайт был на www.
Затем выполнил переезд, удавлив их в поисковике, настроив редирект на без www.
Предварительно настроил переезд в Вебмастере, там сайт настроен как https://sitename.ru
Когда вбиваю в Яндекс запрос "host:www.sitename.ru", высвечивается около 40 страниц, когда "host:www.sitename.ru" - всего три.
1) Важен ли данный фактор?
2) Если да, как исправить ситуацию?
Спасибо, коллеги.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Месяца два назад сайт был на www. Затем выполнил переезд, удавлив их в
>   поисковике, настроив редирект на без www.

Ни Яндекс, ни другие поисковики не отреагируют на Ваши действия сразу (если конечно, это не что-то из ряда вон...).

Своими действиями Вы просто проинформировали поисковик. А, дальше он уже сам по своим алгоритмам будет решать, что и когда ему делать.

Со временем ситуация должна исправиться без каких-либо действий с Вашй стороны.

> Важен ли данный фактор?

Если посещаемость и конверсия не пострадала, думаю, что нет.